# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object Function()'

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

**Hello there...
I nearly has this problem at least at my two pages i did a lot to solve it but it seems i couldn't.
that is my code in product page:**

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ProductModel {
  static const ID = "id";
  static const NAME = "name";
  static const PICTURE = "picture";
  static const PRICE = "price";
  static const DESCRIPTION = "description";

  String _id;
  String _name;
  String _picture;
  String _description;
  

  String get id => _id;

  String get name => _name;

  String get picture => _picture;

  String get brand => _brand;

  String get category => _category;

  String get description => _description;

  ProductModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    _id = snapshot.data[ID];
    _brand = snapshot.data[BRAND];
    _sale = snapshot.data[SALE];
    _description = snapshot.data[DESCRIPTION] ?? " ";
   

  }
}
```

and here it gives that error

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object Function()'.
```

which refers to Models...

and here is the pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_pro: any
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
  firebase_storage: ^10.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.2.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.9
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  firebase_database: ^8.1.0
  flutter_search_panel: any
  intl: ^0.17.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  transparent_image: ^2.0.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  uuid: ^3.0.5
  flutter_typeahead: ^3.2.3
```

I'd be grateful for any help

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
_id = snapshot.data[ID];
_brand = snapshot.data[BRAND];
_sale = snapshot.data[SALE];
_description = snapshot.data[DESCRIPTION] ?? " ";
```

`snapshot.data` is not a map, it is a function that returns a map, so iy should have parenthesis in order to call it:

```
_id = snapshot.data()[ID];
_brand = snapshot.data()[BRAND];
_sale = snapshot.data()[SALE];
_description = snapshot.data()[DESCRIPTION] ?? " ";
```

hopefully that slight change is enough to fix the problem

Comment: Thanks for your help, but again it will not make [BRAND] an order i mean it gives an error ot these

Comment: only on BRAND? Can you show me the error? Does it have to do with the fact that BRAND was not declared on the code you show?

Comment: not only the brand, when i put the shelf () before [ID] or others itself ( i mean the [ID]) will be the error.

i hope you get it because my english not that good.

_brand = snapshot.data()[BRAND];
                                          ---------    

that line is will be red

Comment: Ok but what does the error say? Could you copy-paste the error message or perhaps show a screenshot with the error message visible? Sorry

Comment: Sure, thanks for helping.

it is the link of the image: 
https://ibb.co/tZjSfLf

Comment: Ok, I came up with some fixes, but I am not sure which will help and which won't, and sadly I can't test them for you, first, try changing this line `ProductModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)` to this `ProductModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)` and see if you get the same errors or maybe different ones? then you can add a bang after the `data()`, like this: `snapshot.data()![BRAND]` to make sure it isn't null, finally try changing `snapshot.data()` to `snapshot.data!.data()`, hopefully one of the things I mentioned fixes the issue?

Comment: It worked but it brought some other problems and what then?
https://ibb.co/z8Ts8D1

if i create a Field for snapshot will it solve the problem?

Comment: I solved thank you so much by this code:
(snapshot.data() as DocumentSnapshot)["CART"]

Comment: so it is solved now? Very happy!